# Django admin action with file upload - process file content and put it in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to add some functionality in admin that allows me to upload file and then process it.
I already have a model that I can edit trough the admin, but I want to be able to "upload" multiple items with this file processing.

How can I achieve this in the admin?

Comment: I`m currently trying something - I have created an empty model (with pass instead of fields) and custom form. Now I only wonder where to put the processing - in the form validation or to overwrite the admin save method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions I used is the one described in my comment. Create an empty model (with pass instead of fields), custom admin form and place your logic in the form.

Comment: can you elaborate more on how the custom admin form looks like? that would be helpful

Comment: @Guilherme well, it has been 12 years ago so no idea about that specific case. Normally you can just create a model form and attach it to your admin.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Django Filebrowser](http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/). This app can handle multiple uploads with progressbar and have many other things.

Comment: My problem is not to add file field to the model but to upload a file that have multiple model items data, to process it and put them in the database so this won`t help me.